# Shared Workspaces in R?

Tags: r

Does anyone have a recommendation for sharing workspaces and data frames in R? I'm working at a start-up and we have little experience working in larger production environments where lots of employees are all using the same data.

Is there a way to set permissions on data frames and share them? Or do orgs in our situation just store their data in a database like MySQL and just download it to data frames on a case-by-case basis?

Any tips would be greatly appeciated from those with experience in this area!

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `RMySQL` package for seamless database access.  That seems like a better solution to me, since the database will manage the file locks and so forth for you.

Comment: @gsk3 Yeah, that's what I was originally thinking, but was interested to see if there was a more built-in way to do this. Or just to get a feel for what other orgs do in this case. Thanks!

Comment: There are *a metric ton* of other possibilities. SQL, if you must, is supported via a generic interface called DBI; the the Data Import/Export manual that comes with R. There are also a number of NoSQL solution, or, as I showed, direct ways to dump binary data.

Comment: I'm not sure how big your data is, but I've used dropbox to successfully share .Rdata files between colleagues.

Comment: If you use dropbox to share, wont you both be working on the same file, and eventually dropbox will sync it and stomp on a users changes? Take a copy back-and-forth yeah, but dont work on the same file. Its a fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to dump variables via `save()` to a shared location and have other read those in via `load()` -- it has the added benefits of compression and fast read/write operations for binary modes.

You can of course also serialize to file or a database. Or, if you must, even to human-readable files but those will be the slowest to be read back in.

**Edit** As per comments, here is how to change file modes post-save:

```
R> foo <- 1:3
R> save(foo, file="/tmp/SimpleDemo.RData")
R> Sys.chmod("/tmp/SimpleDemo.RData", mode="0444")
R> system("ls -l /tmp/SimpleDemo.RData")
-r--r--r-- 1 edd edd 62 2011-08-15 16:26 /tmp/SimpleDemo.RData
```

Comment: Thanks. Any known way to make them read-only to guarantee that they have not been changed after being loaded?

Comment: What OS? If you are working on a grown-up system, you can remove the write-permissions after creating the file.

Comment: Using OSX, but I'm looking to remove write permissions from within R. Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: See my most recent edit. And do `install(fortunes); fortunes::fortune("Yoda")` for good measure :)

Answer (score 7):

You can consider using [stashR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stashR/index.html) to make a small server hosting working datasets. It is much more handy than dangling files and is more direct than querying SQL again and again.

As for storing results, the better option is to store scripts that can make them than just results (so-called reproducible research) and manage them using VCS. This of course becomes painful in case of heavy computations, but then one can think of some automatic system that reacts to certain VCS changes and populates some base of intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

save() and load() is the best way to go about it. I additionally use source() to load libraries to make sure that the objects I store using save() get interpreted correctly when I load() them back.

I like to create all of my objects and save() them and reuse them in subsequent session. But, for example, if I saved an xts time series object, upon being reloaded, its meta-structure will not be correctly identified till I execute library(xts).

To see this, you can run

```
str(xts1) #(xts1 is your xts object)
```

before and after loading the xts library.

So it is possible to save() and share all sorts of objects, but you should remember to load the associated library/definition before you start reusing it.